# how to undo the removed tages by using node.remove() .or is it possible to undo this?

Tags: javascript

```
<html>

<body>


<div id="div1">

<p id="p1">This is a paragraph.</p>

<p id="p2">This is another paragraph.</p>

</div>

<script>

var para = document.createElement("h1");

var node = document.createTextNode("<h2>This is new.<h2>");

para.appendChild(node);

var element = document.getElementById("div1");

element.appendChild(para);

element.remove();//is it possible to get "element" variable back 

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Such a `remove` method doesn’t even exist in plain JS, you seem to mixing this with jQuery or other framework syntax …? Using actual vanilla JS/DOM methods, that would be https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild - and that actually returns the reference to the node that was just removed from its parent. And “un-doing” this removal would of course mean _appending_ the element again.

Answer (score 0):

yes .

```
element.style.display=none;
```

undo can be done by clicking a button

```
<button onclick="document.getElementById("div1").style.display=block;">
```